# Button causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exc-bad-access, xib

I have trawled SO for an answer that makes sense to my question, so don't hate me if this is an easy one!

I am adding two views to the window:

```
self.appView = [[AppViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] ;
self.buttonBar = [[ButtonBar alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

[window insertSubview:[self.appView view] belowSubview:[self.launchScreen view]];
[window insertSubview:[self.buttonBar view] belowSubview:[self.launchScreen view]];
```

Before I remove the self.launchScreen.

When I add elements to the appView (it's a uitableviewcontroller) they work as expected, but when I add a button to the buttonBar (either in the XIB or via code), click them causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Here's the init code from buttonBar (which is adding one button):

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        self.settingsButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,10,40,28)];
        [self.settingsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(settings:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    

        UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"];
        [self.settingsButton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnImage release];

        [self.view addSubview:self.settingsButton];

    }
    return self;
}
```

My question is in two parts, 1) WHAT GIVES?!  I've been at this way too long, and 2) How can I debug this stuff? I hate coming to SO to ask n00b questions when I'm sure XCODE's debugging tools would help me track this stuff down...

Comment: Does the 'settings:' method exist in that same object?

Comment: Yes, it reads: -(void)settings { NSLog(@"Settings"); }

Comment: Try '@selector(settings)' instead.

Comment: Deepmist, I want to cry. Put it in an answer so I can give you the tick. Any thoughts on how I can debug this stuff in xcode?

Comment: You might look into NSZombieEnabled.  In the crash report it would tell you what object was trying to call what method when it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@selector(settings)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is the problem but I dont think you need the "retain" at the end in this line

```
self.settingsButton = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,10,40,28)] retain];
```

I'm assuming settingsButton is already in your header file with a @property(retain) and you have synthesized it in your .m file.

release it in the dealloc method instead.

Comment: Sorry, that retain isn't meant to be there. That was me getting wound up and trying everything I could think of. It is synthesized in the .m file, retained in the header and being released in dealloc.